# my up and down arrows don't work in vim

Tags: macos, bash, vim

I just bought a new Macbook Air and my up and down arrows don't work in vim. They work in the bash shell however. But if I try to use them in Vim, I just get the bell.

After more experimentation, I think some vim ruby plugin is messing up my arrow keys.

Comment: @Paul, @Ben: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: @Randy, by that logic "how to adjust my Aeron chair" is a programming question because most Aeron chairs are used by programmers.  This question isn't about setting up macros or fixing the language specific configuration, it's about basic vim setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've notice that you said: (before you edit the question in Stackoverflow)

> I need the arrows for FuzzyFinder and
>   for going back in my Vim command
>   search history.

You can achieve the same with the `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` key combinations,
but you probably need also these in your .vimrc:

```
cnoremap <C-b> <Left>
cnoremap <C-f> <Right>
cnoremap <M-b> <S-Left>
cnoremap <M-f> <S-Right>
```

so you can have the arrows emulation in command mode (search included).

Answer (score 2):

You are likely running Vim in vi compatible mode, which uses <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> for cursor navigation.  Try typing the following command in Vim's command mode:

`:set nocompatible`

If this fixes your problem, you can create a file called **.vimrc** in your home directory (if it doesn't exist already) and add this line to the file:

`set nocompatible`

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `j` to move down and `k` to move up...

Comment: can you use j and k to go back in your vim command history?

Comment: @dan: You can if you use `q:` to bring up the command-line window.

Answer (score 0):

Try running vim as:

```
vim -u NONE --noplugin
```

to prevent any scripts or plugins changing anything, then see if your cursor keys work.
If there's still a problem, it's not caused by your Vim setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in vim in Cygwin. After trying some of the other solutions with no success, I closed my Cygwin terminal and reopened a new one and voila, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Look in the [Vim FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html) for "mapping".